# Join two tuples in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I've got two tuples, `std::tuple<F1, F2, ..., FN>`, `std::tuple<G1, G2, ..., GN>` (or `std::tuple<G1>` aka `G1`). Is there any way to join these tuples generically into a `std::tuple<F1, F2, ..., FN, G1, G2, ..., GN>` if any of the types `F1`, `F2`, ..., `FN`, `G1`, `G2`, ..., `GN` does not have a default constructor, but is movable / swapable?

Comment: This is how you can define an equivalent of `std::tuple_cat` yourself: https://gist.github.com/VladimirReshetnikov/10684cb56c37cbe6c162bba694dd77b6

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`std::tuple_cat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat)

```
std::tuple<foo, bar, baz> buzz;
std::tuple<moo, meow, arf> bark;

auto my_cat_tuple = std::tuple_cat(buzz, std::move(bark));  // copy elements of buzz,
                                                            // move elements of bark
```

The above will work if the element types of the tuples are movable or copyable. And it does not require them to be default constructible unless you're doing something like

```
decltype(std::tuple_cat(buzz, bark)) my_uncatted_yet_tuple;  // This will attempt to default construct the tuple elements

my_uncatted_yet_tuple = std::tuple_cat(buzz, std::move(bark));
```